# What is 'relevance time'?

Tags: terminology, time

What is ‘relevance time’ in the chart below? And would you compare it with ‘narrative time’?

[image]
(Angela Downing, English Grammar: A University Course)

[image]
[(StoneyB's answer in ELL)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/reasons-for-these-two-past-perfect-tenses)

Comment: It looks to me like her *relevance time* is what I was taught to call *Reference time* - which in a narrative I give the distinctive name Narrative time, because in narratives (unlike ordinary isolated sentences) it doesn't stand still but moves 'forward'.

Comment: Then what's the difference from 'speech time'?

Comment: And by the way - I'm beginning to think Jim's point  about the relative clause (at that earlier answer) is at least half right, maybe more: that the past tense in that case, like the 'found' above, isn't part of the same sequence but a 'branch line'. But I'm going to have to puzzle on that.

Comment: *Speech time* (or *Utterance time*) is the time at which the sentence is written or uttered: the 'present'.

Comment: There's some bumph about the distinction [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-QUcAQAAIAAJ&q=%22relevance+time%22+%22reference+time%22&dq=%22relevance+time%22+%22reference+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DwZVUd3XFe_40gXq8oGADw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA), but I think the short answer for ELL is that @StoneyB is correct - they're effectively equivalent for most purposes. Maybe [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to dig any deeper than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Reference Time refers to the time that has already gone by or the past. Narrative time, is the continuation or the present/future events.

The example is nicely given.

Complete Sentence :: I had once vowed never to smoke a cigarette. So many years have passed since I started the habit. Now I think it isn't a sin any longer.

**Reference Time**

This is an event that has already happened. So in our story, the Reference time is the time that evolved in this part ::

*I had once vowed never to smoke a cigarette*

During the past, at some point in childhood, or many years ago, I decided never to smoke. That is the reference time. It ends once we leave the past and move to the present.

**Narative Time**

This is the event that is happening now or in the future. In our sentence that is ::

*So many years have passed since I started the habit. Now I think it isn't a sin any longer.*

The years have passed (in the past), the present has arrived. Now (again indicates the present), I think it isn't a sin any longer.