# Meaning of progressive: “were seeing” vs “saw”

Tags: meaning, tense, aspect

> (1) We still **saw** each other a couple of times a month.  [(MacMillandictionary.com)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/see#see_22) 
>     * I changed the verb 'saw' from 'see' 
>   (2) They **were seeing** so much of each other, he was almost one of the family. (Angela Downing, English Grammar: A University Course)

What’s the difference in meaning between selecting progressive, or not?

Comment: Then, when I correct the first to "We still saw each other -" is the question proper?

Comment: Yes, I'd better change the first.

Comment: From the FAQ (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference in *meaning* between the two...

> 1: We still saw each other a couple of times a month
>    2: We were still seeing each other a couple of times a month

The only difference is that the [reference/relevance/narrative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/what-is-relevance-time) time has subtly altered. In both versions the meetings being described are in the speaker's past, but by introducing the *past progressive*, #2 has expanded the "potential scope" of that past. Consider...

> 1a: ?We still saw each other a couple of times a month when her mother died
>    2a: We were still seeing each other a couple of times a month when her mother died

I've put a question mark against #1a because I'm guessing many people would agree with me it doesn't work if the intended meaning is *"at the time when"*. You could "fix" it by replacing *"when"* with *"after"*, if that's the meaning you want anyway - but for my purposes here, ***I*** want it to mean *"before, at the time when, **and** after"*. That's not something you can really do with the simple past as used in #1.

Effectively, using *past progressive* expands that "reference time" in the past, so it can encompass other events that might even have their own chronological sequence...

> 2b: We were still seeing each other regularly when first her mother, then her father, died.